# ros1 zsh completion

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

Having no tab-completion for `ros*` commands (i.e. `roslaunch`, `rosrun`) after sourcing a `setup.zsh` file. The `ros*` commands are available to call; there's simply no aid in auto-completing pkg's name, launch file, arguments, etc.

Completion works within the `bash` shell after sourcing a `setup.bash` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not have this in the .zshrc:

> `zstyle ':completion:*' use-compctl false`

Make it `true` or do not specify at all (`true` is the default value).

After trying out a clean Oh-My-Zsh installation, I was surprised that the completion worked there. The problem lied within my own, custom `.zshrc` configuration. Apparently, having `use-compctl` set to `false` broke auto-completion just for the `ros*` commands and seemingly nothing else.